# php - move uploaded file evaluating to false

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a php file setup for uploading images to an Amazon server via AWS. I've come to an error message which strangely is showing up on my prod server (the amazon server) but not my dev server (just a regular php server). The Amazon server has previously thrown errors when something is not structured exactly how it wants. For example if a an a tag has a href `/home` it will lead to an error page unless I change the tag to `/home/`.

Anyway i''ve narrowed down in my PHP script where the error lies and my php function `move_uploaded_file`is evaluating to false and stopping my file from beginning the upload to Amazon s3 (at this stage the file is on the server where the site is hosted but not yet on the s3). Here is my if statement with some variables declared above that should be evaluating to true:

```
$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)) {
    //upload to s3
} else {
    //error
}
```

I inserted the following code above the if statement to see what it was spitting out and here's what it evaluated in comments under it:

```
echo json_encode($target_file);
//     "..\/uploads\/Grad.jpeg"

   echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
    //    /tmp/phpQA1667

  echo json_encode(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file));
    //    false
```

I'm no php expert and can't seem to put my finder on why it's evaluating to false. Can anyone see where i've gone wrong?

Comment: Was the file moved, did you checked that?

Comment: maybe you cannot go to ../uploads/ ? you can echo __DIR__; to display where your absolute path currently is and then you have to see if you actually have ../uploads .

if the path is correct, i would check the rights of the folder

Comment: sorry but echo DIR; only echoes out a string saying DIR. Not sure if im doing this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move_uploaded_file returns false in two cases:

If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE.

If filename is a valid upload file, but cannot be moved for some reason, no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE. Additionally, a warning will be issued.

Either way, you should be getting an error back in your $_FILES superglobal.

Do a print_r($_FILES) and have a look at any error messages it gives you, and whether or not the array is populated.

Once you find that error, it should be easy for you to determine the exact cause of the issue.

A comprehensive list of the errors can be found at http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php